# css :nth-child() :after

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to mix `:nth-child()` and `after`?

I have an `<ol>` of items and I want to add some text `:after`.  This works fine but I'd then like to have different text on 1st, 2nd and 3rd items and then 4th, 5th and 6th as well.

With the below code I end up with every `li` having 'large' in pink after it.

This doesn't make sense to me however I am new to this `nth-child` malarky.

**data.html**

```
<ol id="id" class="ui-sortable">
    <li>
        <p>Bacon</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Bacon</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Bacon</p>
    </li>

    <!.. repeats -->

    <li>
        <p>Bacon</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**pretty.css**

```css
#id li p:after {
    float: right;
    content: 'nom';
}

#id li p:nth-child(1):after,
#id li p:nth-child(2):after,
#id li p:nth-child(3):after {
    content: 'OM';
    color: pink;
}

#id li p:nth-child(4):after,
#id li p:nth-child(5):after,
#id li p:nth-child(6):after {
    content: 'Nom';
    color: blue;
}
```

I'd really like not to do this with js as it just a 'nice to have' feature.

I'm only worried about new browsers so no need for workarounds for oldIE etc.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can, but you are doing it wrong..

The issue that that all your `p` elements are inside `li`. So all of them are the first child of their `li` container.

You will need to put the `nth-child` on the `li` elements.

```css
#id li:nth-child(1) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(2) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(3) p:after {
    content: 'OM';
    color: pink;
}

#id li:nth-child(4) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(5) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(6) p:after {
    content: 'Nom';
    color: blue;
}
```

---

Quoting [the W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 **siblings before it** in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, and has a parent element.

---

**Update 1**

You could also simplify this by using

```css
#id li:nth-child(-n+3) p:after {
    content: 'OM';
    color: pink;
}

#id li:nth-last-child(-n+3) p:after { /*this means last 3*/
    content: 'Nom';
    color: blue;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4H4AS/2/

---

**Update 2**

If you want the first six only to be different (*and not first 3 and last 3*) you could

```css
#id li:nth-child(-n+6) p:after { /*this means first 6*/
    content: 'Nom';
    color: blue;
}

#id li:nth-child(-n+3) p:after {/*this means first 3 and since it comes second it has precedence over the previous for the common elements*/
    content: 'OM';
    color: pink;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/4H4AS/3/

Answer (score 7):

Should be done like this:

```css
#id li:nth-child(1) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(2) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(3) p:after {
    content: 'OM';
    color: pink;
}
#id li:nth-child(4) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(5) p:after,
#id li:nth-child(6) p:after {
    content: 'Nom';
    color: blue;
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/4H4AS/)

... as `<p>` is always the first child of `<li>` in the shown HTML structure.

Take note, though, that `content: 'nom';` rule in the very first style definition was overwritten (but 'float' rule stood): it's the same cascading ruling for the ':after' pseudo-element as for the others. )

Comment: What an annoyingly obvious mistake.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep that's working well now, thanks.  The idea is every item has 'nom' but the first 6 are different so the cascade works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the psudeos like so...

```
#id li:nth-child(1)::before {
    border-left-color: red;
}
#id li:nth-child(2)::before {
    border-left-color: white;
}
#id li:nth-child(3)::before {
    border-left-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is what a lot of readers coming from search engines will look for.