# cant style :nth-child(odd)::after

Tags: html, css

Ive found similar questions on here, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957498/css-nth-child-after) but I cant get it to work for my case..

So I have a list like so..

```
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
  </ul>
```

and what Im trying to do is for every second item in the list add a `::after` that does something in this case to be used as a background

what Ive tried is to do this...

```
.list li:nth-child(odd)::after{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#8CC63F, #128465);
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

the reason I am doing this is because I want the background to be transparent and not the entire `li` elemnt

but I cant seem to get it to work?

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: and you don't set any `content` to these pseudo elements?

Comment: @Kaiido what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use absolute position with your after element:

```css
.list li:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
}

.list li:nth-child(odd)::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #8CC63F, #128465);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
</ul>
```

But you can also apply the gradient directly to `li` using `rgba` color:

```css
.list li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(140, 198, 63, 0.7), rgba(18, 132, 101, 0.7));
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use Below css. It might solve your problem

```
.list li:nth-child(odd)::after{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
content: '';
background: linear-gradient(to right,#8CC63F, #128465);
opacity: 0.7;
display:inline-block;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

}

Comment: what is the purpose of doing a copy past of the answer already accepted 6h ago ?