# How to set :before psudo property for a group of css styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set :before psudo property for a set of css styles,

```
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) .serveroutput-pop, 
  .two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop,
  .two-row-three-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(2) .serveroutput-pop,
  .one-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop  {
      left: -397px;
      right: auto;
  }
```

My expected code is like,

```
 (.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) .serveroutput-pop, 
  .two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop,
  .two-row-three-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(2) .serveroutput-pop,
  .one-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop)::before  {
      left: -458px;
      right: auto;
  }
```

Comment: That's impossible to do with css. You will need SASS or something.

Comment: ref this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957498/css-nth-child-after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the before for each line like this. So it works properly

```
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) .serveroutput-pop::before, 
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop::before,
.two-row-three-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(2) .serveroutput-pop::before,
.one-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop::before  {
      left: -397px;
      right: auto;
  }
```

Comment: its just a guess and depents of your HTML Code... If you have an additional class you could reduce it by using attribute selectors, e.x. `div[class*="serveroutput-pop"]:before` means all divs which have this ( * -> and additional) classes.

Answer (score 1):

With CSS only, its not possible at the moment. You may add the `:before` after every selector, like this:

```
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) .serveroutput-pop:before, 
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop:before,
.two-row-three-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(2) .serveroutput-pop:before,
.one-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop:before  {
  left: -397px;
  right: auto;
}
```

An possibility, is to use CSS preprocessors, so you could add it only once, like this example in **SASS**:

```
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(3) .serveroutput-pop, 
.two-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop,
.two-row-three-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(2) .serveroutput-pop,
.one-row-two-column mat-grid-tile:nth-of-type(1) .serveroutput-pop {
  &:before{
    left: -397px;
    right: auto;
  }
}
```

Check more about SASS here, in the [official guide](https://sass-lang.com/guide).